# How to get value using python selenium of element that is not selectable

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

I am trying to get a value 570 using Python selenium.

```
...
<div _ngcontent-lci-c225="" class="mr-4 bd-highlight">
    <span _ngcontent-lci-c225="" class="clickable ng-star-inserted" style="margin-right: 5px;">Bank</span>
    <!---->
    570
    </div>
```

I am not sure what  is and why when I highlight it in chrome dev tools it doesn't show me anything in styles window where I would usually see something. Tried googling to get the meaning of  without success. If anyone knows please explain to me.

My code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div[4]/mat-drawer-container/mat-drawer-content/mat-grid-list/div/mat-grid-tile[2]/figure/app-inventory-menu/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

It returns 'Bank' and not the actual numerical value that I need. Not sure what else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for suggestion I was able to figure it out.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.inventory-row:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)").text.strip("Bank")
```

Maybe there is a better way, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the number is not contained within the `<span>` element, but rather the `<div>` element above it. Based on your code, the best selector I can find for it is the CSS Selector: `"div.mr-4.bd-highlight"`

Comment: Thank you for this, i was able to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
parent = driver.find_element(By.CSS_ELECTOR,"mr-4.bd-highlight")
child = parent.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"span")
print (parent.text.replace(child.text, ''))
```

Try to remove the span text. I know there's a way better way then this using split.